# How to unset the 'http_proxy' environment variable in Python

Tags: linux, python, environment-variables, proxy

I am using below python code to reset the environment variable `http_proxy` in  Linux CentOS 6, but it is not unsetting the variable for the rest of the Python script.

Code:

```
 import os 
 print "Unsetting http..." 
 os.system("unset http_proxy") 
 os.system("echo $http_proxy") 
 print "http is reset"
```

Output:

```
Unsetting http...
http://web-proxy.xxxx.xxxxxxx.net:8080
http is reset
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: @Kusalananda , I want to reset the system 'http_proxy' , to open an internal url using python automation script and then want to set the http_proxy back to run the external url. It is just to run my automation script I need to toggle between reset and set proxy

Comment: That makes it clearer, thanks.  I have updated the text of your question with some of that information.

Answer (score 11):

Each invocation of `os.system()` runs in its own subshell, with its own fresh environment:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("echo $$")
97678
0
>>> os.system("echo $$")
97679
0
```

You *are* unsetting the `http_proxy` variable, but then your subshell has completed executing the command (to wit: `unset`), and terminates.  You then start a new subshell with a new environment in which to run `echo`.

I believe what you are trying to do is `del os.environ['http_proxy']`, or `os.environ.pop('http_proxy')` if you want to ensure there is no `http_proxy` environment variable whether or not one previously existed:

```
$ export foo=bar
$ python2
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 15 2017, 17:16:57)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['foo']
'bar'
>>> del os.environ['foo']
>>> os.system('echo $foo')

0
```

Comment: [The putenv/unsetenv API is basically broken in Python](https://ideone.com/hKck3c), because `getenv` goes through `os.environ`, but `putenv` and `unsetenv` don't update `os.environ`. putenv and unsetenv update the environment variables, but there's no way to examine their effects through either `os.environ` or `getenv`. It's much better to delete the key from `os.environ`.

Comment: [A related issue has been languishing on the tracker for over a decade.](https://bugs.python.org/issue1159)

Comment: To clarify: does deleting the key from `os.environ` actually DTRT and remove the environment variable?

Comment: Yes: ["If the platform supports the unsetenv() function, you can delete items in this mapping to unset environment variables. unsetenv() will be called automatically when an item is deleted from os.environ, and when one of the pop() or clear() methods is called."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) Same with putenv: if the platform has putenv, setting keys in `os.environ` will automatically perform the corresponding putenv calls. I'm not sure what platforms don't have those functions, but the docs say "Availability: most flavors of Unix, Windows."

Comment: That does bring up a caveat I should have thought to mention earlier, which is that if the platform *doesn't* have putenv/unsetenv, attempting to call those functions directly will throw an error, while modifying `os.environ` will just have no effect on environment variables. On such platforms (whichever ones they are), you have to launch subprocesses with a function that accepts an explicit environment dict instead of `os.system` if you want to set environment variables for subprocesses. You can check if you're on such a platform with `hasattr(os, 'putenv')` and `hasattr(os, 'unsetenv')`.

Answer (score 4):

Each call to `os.system()` is creating a separate process.  Do `echo $$` inside them both to see that the PID changes with each.

So your first `os.system()` spawns a new process which inside of itself `unset`s one variable.  This doesn't effect the variables values in the process of the python script.  Then the first spawned process exits and you spawn a new process.  The second `os.system()` spawns this new process which inherits all of the environment variables from the python script - which haven't been touched.  So of course the second spawned process sees the variable, because it was never `unset` in the process of the python script so it won't missing from any new child processes.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575165/what-is-the-correct-way-to-unset-a-linux-environment-variable-in-python for how to do this in python and http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.environ for the official docs.

Comment: Now if I want to set new http_proxy manually for the CentOS 6.6 , then what is the correct way to do it permanently. I am using CentOS 6.6 image inside Vmware Workstation.